# Search within the search results of an MYSQL Query

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, search

I'm writing an app in java, that receives requests and save them to a file,
then it can search the old requests.

I started to upgrade my app to use MySQL instead of a plain Txt file.

**I am looking for a way to query the DataBase in the following way:**

I am looking for requests that were opened in (Specific Dates)-**First Search** , that contain the word xxx -**second search**

**I found this query:**

```
SELECT * FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests WHERE ClosingTimeStamp LIKE "%2014-09-01%" 
OR ClosingTimeStamp LIKE "%2014-09-02%" ;
```

This gives me all the lines that was created in these dates,
I want the query to return only the lines within these results that contains the specific word too...

For example :

**this query will return:**

1,bannaba, i want to be alive,2014-09-01

6,apple, woo hoo, 2014-09-02

7,Mango, groove is in the heart,2014-09-02

**i need a query that will return only lines that contain the word "apple" in one of its columns:**

6,apple, woo hoo, 2014-09-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is a very bad way to search for date times.  The following is a bit better:

```
SELECT *
FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests
WHERE date(ClosingTimeStamp) = '2014-09-01' OR date(ClosingTimeStamp) = 2014-09-02';
```

If you have no time component to the time stamp, then remove the `date()` function.  Only use `like` on strings.

An even better way is:

```
SELECT *
FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests
WHERE ClosingTimeStamp >= '2014-09-01' AND ClosingTimeStamp < 2014-09-03';
```

The latter will allow the engine to use an index on `ClosingTimeStamp`.

If you want to add another condition, just add it:

```
SELECT *
FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests
WHERE ClosingTimeStamp >= '2014-09-01' AND ClosingTimeStamp <= 2014-09-03' AND
      col2 = 'Apple';
```

SQL doesn't have a built-in concept of saving query results for another query.  You can implement such functionality, but it is probably not needed for your application.  You can just add conditions to the `where` clause.

Comment: what does col2 stands for ? I want the word search to search the entire row, so I can search id, comment, or name in the same search.

Comment: You don't name your columns in the question, so one has to guess at column names.  If you want to search through multiple columns, then add additional clauses to the `where`:  `'Apple' in (col2, col3, col4, col5)`.

Comment: can I use "*" instead of adding all 8 columns ?

Comment: this is the best way I could find:                                SELECT * FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests 
WHERE
ClosingTimeStamp >= '2014-09-17'
AND
ClosingTimeStamp <= '2014-09-30'
AND
(Computerip) LIKE "%24%"
OR
(ComputerName) LIKE "%24%"
OR
(TechComment) LIKE "%24%"
OR
(RequestComment) LIKE "%24%";

Comment: @DavidGidony . . . In general, you cannot use `*` in the `where` clause.  You need to list out the columns.

Comment: 10x, just wanted to make sure I'm using the best way :)  the dates <= was brilliant :)

Answer (score 0):

Use nested SELECT.  But the inner SELECT should not use * so that the collumn can be referenced from the outer SELECT.

```
SELECT col_1 (SELECT col_1, col_2 FROM requestserverdb.closedrequests WHERE ClosingTimeStamp LIKE "%2014-09-01%" OR ClosingTimeStamp LIKE "%2014-09-02%") WHERE col_1 LIKE "%XXX%";
```

something to that affect.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than searching for the date, why don't you just search for a record which contains the word apple? The other way could be is to have 2 WHERE conditions. One that contins the date and one that contains the word Apple